# LibGDX: Shape from ShapeRenderer won't show up when put in another class

Tags: java, libgdx

I am currently trying to make a little snake clone as my second project with LibGDX. I want to draw the borders of the screen with a ShapeRenderer. The Shape gets displayed flawlessly when I create/draw it in the render method of my game. I wanted to outsource the code into an own "Border"-Class, to get a single object for collision and graphics, but if I do this, the shape does 
not get displayed anymore.

**Working code before outsourcing to a Border-Class:**

```
public void render(float dt){

...
borderRenderer = new ShapeRenderer();
    borderRenderer.begin(ShapeRenderer.ShapeType.Filled);
    borderRenderer.setProjectionMatrix(gameCam.combined);
    borderRenderer.setColor(1.0f, 0.3f, 0.3f, 1);
    borderRenderer.rect(x , y , width, height);
    borderRenderer.end();
}
```

**ShapeRenderer outsourced, gets not displayed anymore:**

```
public void render(float dt){
...
for (Border border : borders) {
            border.draw();
        }
}

public class Border {
    private ShapeRenderer borderRenderer;
    private OrthographicCamera gameCam;
    private float x, y, width, height;

    public Border(float x, float y, float width, float height, OrthographicCamera gameCam){
        this.gameCam = gameCam;
        this.borderRenderer = new ShapeRenderer();
    }

    public void draw(){
        borderRenderer.begin(ShapeRenderer.ShapeType.Filled);
        borderRenderer.setProjectionMatrix(gameCam.combined);
        borderRenderer.setColor(1.0f, 0.3f, 0.3f, 1);
        borderRenderer.rect(x , y , width, height);
        borderRenderer.end();

    }

}
```

The border also gets properly initialized in the constructor.

As I was writing this I recognized that using assets for this would probably be a better idea, but I'm still curious.
Thanks in advance for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Border constructor you never assign `x`, `y`, `width`, or `height` to local variables, which means they all default to 0. Once I added those assignments the rest of the code worked fine for me.

Comment: Thanks for your response.The values get initialized properly. Maybe I should have made it clearer that this is not the issue.

Comment: You were right ! I have no idea how I could have been this blind. Thank you very much.